# Using multiple filters in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, owl

I want to get the Job ID passed as parameter and check the id with the id in the owl file and then, match the job skill of that job id to the skill of the candidates (candidates also contain skills). I am getting the url parameter and storing in a variable.

```
String jobID = request.getParameter("JobID");

String query =
                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
                        "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> " +
                        "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
                        "PREFIX ns0: <http://www.Jobsurveillance.com/CV#> " +
                        "SELECT (str(?object) as ?label) " +
                        "(str(?object2) as ?label2) " +
                        "(str (?phoneNumobj) as ?label3) " +
                        "(str (?degreeobj) as ?label4) " +
                        "(str (?jobcatObj) as ?label5) " +
                        "(str (?candidateSkill) as ?label8) " +
                        "(str (?jobAdID) as ?label6) " +
                        "(str (?jobSkill) as ?label7) WHERE { " +
                        " ?person ns0:Full_Name ?object ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Email_Id ?object2 ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Phone_Number ?phoneNumobj ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Degree ?degreeobj ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Job_Category ?jobcatObj ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Skills ?candidateSkill ." +
                        " ?job ns0:JobID ?jobAdID ." +
                        " ?job ns0:JobSkills ?jobSkill ." +
                        " filter (regex(?jobAdID, \"" + jobID + "\") ." +
                        " filter (?jobSkill = ?candidateSkill)) ." +
                        "}";
```

When I run i get an error like below:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "." ". "" at line 1, 
column 756.
Was expecting one of:
"not" ...
"in" ...
<INTEGER_POSITIVE> ...
<DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ...
<DOUBLE_POSITIVE> ...
<INTEGER_NEGATIVE> ...
<DECIMAL_NEGATIVE> ...
<DOUBLE_NEGATIVE> ...
")" ...
"=" ...
"!=" ...
">" ...
"<" ...
"<=" ...
">=" ...
"||" ...
"&&" ...
"+" ...
"-" ...
"*" ...
"/" ...
```

My Dataset is as follows

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.Jobsurveillance.com/CV#Candidate6">
  <rdf:type>
    <owl:Restriction>
      <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.Jobsurveillance.com/CV#includes"/>
      <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.Jobsurveillance.com/CV#CV"/>
    </owl:Restriction>
  </rdf:type>

  <ns0:Address rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Colombo 15</ns0:Address>
  <ns0:Company rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">TechOrin</ns0:Company>
  <ns0:Degree rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">B.Sc (Hons), Information Technology</ns0:Degree>
  <ns0:Email_Id rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">yashmitha@gmail.com</ns0:Email_Id>
  <ns0:Skills rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Java</ns0:Skills>
  <ns0:Job_Category rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Marketing</ns0:Job_Category>
  <ns0:Full_Name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Yashmitha</ns0:Full_Name>
  <ns0:Phone_Number rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">0723679017</ns0:Phone_Number>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

This is my SPARQL query. Am I implementing the filter in the correct way. Could anyone pl help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: And now? What is the problem? what is the error? What does not work as expected? if it is a `jobID`, why do you do a REGEX instead of exact match? we don't know your data, nor do we know an example taht doesn't work ...

Comment: @AKSW I have updated my issue. There are multiple job ids. It should get the user input job id and match.

Comment: And **again**, you're using an old Jena version, although we told you last time to upgrade and you also put it as an answer ... may I ask why?

Comment: And what means there are multiple job IDs? why does this matter? what is a JobID? a String literal?

Comment: `filter (?jobSkill = ?candidateSkill))` - here is also a syntactic issue ...

Comment: if a job has mutliple job IDs, this means it has multiple triple, or not? in that case, don't use a regex, but exact match

Comment: by the way, yesterday you also haven't be able to reply to my comment? if you solved the issue with the union, please provide the answer and mark the question as answered.

Comment: ... no you added sample data for the candidates, but not for the job ID ... anyways, I gave you the answer (syntax error + datatype of the literal). For the future, showing data as N-Triples (or Turtle) makes much more sense as this directly reflects the language of triple patterns in SPARQL.

Comment: @AKSW The datatype of the JobID is integer. I don't understand what you mean by the syntax error? Can u pls provide the correct syntax?

Comment: @AKSW I haven't still found the answer for the question posted yday. Your solution didn't actually help

Comment: the datatype of job ID is integer, but you"re doing a regex? again, why not just do exact match here?

Comment: you don"t see the syntax error in `filter (?jobSkill = ?candidateSkill))` ??? one open brace two closing braces ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Issue FIXED by correcting the filter syntax and matching the JobID to the attribute value.

Comment: Then, please provide it as an answer and click on "accept".

Comment: Regarding the other question with the union, what did not work? And why are you again using an old Jena version here?! I don't get this given that we already told you in a previous question that you should use 3.8.0 instead of 2.x

Comment: I updated the version to 3.8.0 after you recommended. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISSUE SOLVED. The query below helped me get the exact output which I needed

```
String query =
                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
                        "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> " +
                        "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
                        "PREFIX ns0: <http://www.Jobsurveillance.com/CV#> " +
                        "SELECT (str(?object) as ?label) " +
                        "(str(?object2) as ?label2) " +
                        "(str (?phoneNumobj) as ?label3) " +
                        "(str (?degreeobj) as ?label4) " +
                        "(str (?jobcatObj) as ?label5) " +
                        "(str (?candidateSkill) as ?label8) " +
                        "(str (?jobSkill) as ?label7) WHERE { " +
                        " ?person ns0:Full_Name ?object ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Email_Id ?object2 ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Phone_Number ?phoneNumobj ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Degree ?degreeobj ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Job_Category ?jobcatObj ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Skills ?candidateSkill ." +
                        " ?job ns0:JobID  \"" + jobID + "\"." +
                        " ?job ns0:JobSkills ?jobSkill ." +
                        " filter (?jobSkill = ?candidateSkill)" +
                        "}";
```

In the above code the below line which was

```
filter (?jobSkill = ?candidateSkill))
```

is corrected as

```
filter (?jobSkill = ?candidateSkill)
```

Comment: As I read this, the actual answer was "fix syntax of specific line(s)".  You should change this to show exactly that -- the bad line(s), and the correction(s).

Comment: Also note that the SPARQL query (which had the problem) is obscured by being wrapped in Java code. You will get faster SPARQL answers by providing only the SPARQL query, without the Java wrapping. This can also expose errors in your Java wrapping (commonly, leaving out necessary SPARQL whitespace when breaking the query across lines of Java).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!